# How to get the last array iteration in javascript in a map function?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an Array of objects in a **messages** constant which are 3 keys /values : **author**, **hour** and **message**

Problem : some object have a blank **author** value, and I want to get the previous iteration  **author** key/value in the .map function itself to replace the blank value (current iteration)

Is it possible to get the previous iteration element in the .map function even if the iteration is not yet finished ?

Thanks a lot for your help

From this

```
0:
author: "Kara"
hour: "19:32"
message: "Salut Mia merci pour ton ajout cela va me servir de test !"
1:
author: ""
hour: ""
message: "Ceci est un test : message 2 !!"
```

To this :

```
0:
author: "Kara"
hour: "19:32"
message: "Salut Mia merci pour ton ajout cela va me servir de test !"
1:
author: "Kara"
hour: "19:32"
message: "Ceci est un test : message 2 !!"
```

I want to copy the previous iteration object values.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get the previous iteration element in the .map function even if the iteration is not yet finished ?

Yes. The second argument is the current index and the third argument is the array itself, so you can just access `array[index - 1]` inside the `.map` callback. That won't work for the first element though (as there is no previous element).

Comment: A small code example might be handy - the asker might not even know that `map` gives its callback function index/array arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index from the handler:

```
array.map((o, index, arr) => {
   let previous = arr[index - 1]; // For index === 0, the previous object will be undefined.
});
```

Go and read about it `->` [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

```
array.map((ele, index, arr) => {
   let keys = Object.keys(ele);
   keys.each((key) => {
    if (ele[key] === '') {
     ele[key] = arr[index - 1][key];
    }
   });
   return ele;
});
```